# Crontab doesn't have credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cron, dockerfile

I have a script that I can run interactively from `root` which requires AWS credentials. However, when I run this script via crontab, I get a `No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials/root` error. This error relates to `aws` credentials. I have other scripts running succesfully with crontab.

The crontab looks like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
* * * * * root echo “28/11 test” >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
35 14 * * * root /usr/bin/python /full_path/api_60.py && root /usr/bin/python /full_path/api_300.py && root /usr/bin/python /full_path/api_3600.py
40 14 * * * root /usr/bin/python /full_path/daily_push_s3.py
```

I made sure that the `SHELL` and `PATH` variables were correct by using `echo` to find them from the interactive shell where the scripts definitely work.

I read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/614890/cant-run-aws-cli-from-cron-credentials) that `aws` looks in `~/.aws` for the config or credentials files.

I thus moved the config and credential files to `/root/.aws/` instead of `~/.aws/` and set `ENV HOME=/root`.

credentials:

```
[default]
region=eu-west-1
output=json
```

config:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXX
```

What is the difference in environments?

Comment: Did you move the credentials file?

Comment: Without knowing what is in your `config` or `credentials` file, it is difficult to comment. You should move/copy `~/.aws` to `/root/.aws`. You need both `config` and `credentials`.

Comment: Thanks @helloV. I've made some edits. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Since the crontab environment trumps any pre-defined environment I added the credentials directly there and all worked.

```
HOME=/root
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
AWS_CONFIG_FILE=“/path/config”
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXX"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="XXX"
```